# Offset CFrame Math

Tags: lua, roblox

So, for my FPS Framework, I want to make automated Aim Downs Sights, i.e., without using an animation.

The issue is that I have to move the:-

- Arms
- Weapon
  But I can't do that without welding the arms to the weapon, but I need the arms welded to the RootPart instead.

So I took a rig and started experimenting, and I came up with a solution!

- An anchored part will be taken as the camera(this is just for testing purposes)
- The RootPart will be welded to the CameraPart
- There will be a AimPart which defines where the camera should be in order to make the player feel like they are aiming down sights.

And I came up with this

```lua
local AimPartPosition = (Camera.CFrame:inverse() * AimPart.CFrame).Position
CamWeld.C0 = CamWeld.C0 * CFrame.new(Vector3.new(-AimPartPosition.X,-AimPartPosition.Y,-AimPartPosition.Z))
```

Here, I get the offset of the AimPart from the CameraPart, and then reverse the position and finally apply that to the offset of RootPart to CameraPart.(The reason I put `.Position` is because I only want to reverse the Position and not the Rotation, just to be safe).

This works very well and I am proud I did it, but I feel like not using that extra CameraPart. I want to use RAW CFrame values instead of Motor6Ds.

This obviously wouldn't work...

```lua
local AimPartPosition = (Camera.CFrame:inverse() * AimPart.CFrame).Position
RootPart.CFrame = Camera.CFrame:inverse() * RootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(Vector3.new(-AimPartPosition.X,-AimPartPosition.Y,-AimPartPosition.Z))
```

Because

```lua
RootPart.CFrame ~= Camera.CFrame:inverse() * RootPart.CFrame
```

I have the offset I need to apply to the RootPart, I just do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
RootPart.CFrame = RootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(Vector3.new(-AimPartPosition.X,-AimPartPosition.Y,-AimPartPosition.Z))
```

Well that felt like cheating I'm gonna be honest.